# C# List<T> out of memory exception but far away from the 2Gb limit

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

I have a `List<Matrix4>`, where `Matrix4` is a struct containing 16 floats, so it uses 16 * 4 bytes = 64 bytes.

When I start adding items to the list it throws an Out Of Memory Exception when I cross the 1 million line.

I know that .NET have a limit of 2Gb per object, but unless I'm completely out of my mind:

1.000.000 * 64 bytes = ~61mb

Which is not even close to the limit.

When I start populating the list, according to task manager, my application is using 896mb and by the time I reach the exception it's using 1028mb.

The computer has 8GB of physical memory but it's using only 6Gb.

Any clues on why is could be happening?

--- UPDATE ----

Changing the platform target to x64 solved the issue on a separate test project. Unfortunately the original project cannot be x64 due references do x86 DLLs that do not work on x64. But that's another problem.

I didn't thought on changing it to x64 because it seemed to be far from the memory limits, but I guess Hans Passant was right on 122mb being too close from the 1.3Gb limit. Thank you all.

Comment: Not that its the answer, but you can't count .NET memory allocation like that.

Comment: you should use the tooling in Visual Studio to profile the memory usage.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx

Comment: I don't think that's the answer too. But, every object in .NET has header with information. In 32bit app the header is 8bytes length, in 64bit app the header is 16bytes length. So, EACH float consumes 12bytes length (in 32bit app). Without seeing more of code is impossible point what's the problem.

Comment: @RicardoSilva: `Matrix4` is a *struct*, and so is `float`. Neither of those is an object.

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? I don't have any problems reaching 10 million...

Comment: What processes/instructions do you execute between 2 additions to the list? _It's to know what kind of memory allocation/disposal are made_.

Comment: Just a clarification, everything in C# is object. Any struct has ToString or GetType methods, also for float. This is because they inherit Object class.

Comment: The list works with an array internally that more or less doubles in size every time it reaches its maximum. Even if you have only 10 items in your list the size of the underlying array can be bigger. Maybe that has something to do with the problem. Try initializing the list with the number of items. The list source code can be foung here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,aa9d469618cd43b0,references

Comment: @RicardoSilva All types (barring pointers) are *implicitly convertible* to objects.  That doesn't mean they *are* objects.  A boxing operation is necessary to turn a value type into an `object`, although all value types can indeed be boxed into objects.

Comment: @RicardoSilva - no need to lecture the basics here. An array of 1Mx4xfloat will be 64M in one piece. And yes, that piece has a header, so the final tally is 64M+8.

Comment: The simple, and common, explanation is that you forced your program to run in 32-bit mode.  The default setting for a .NET project.  So all that wonderful hardware you have is largely unused.  Once you get to 1028MB, you start to risk address space fragmentation problems, the GC needs to find a hole in which it can shoe-horn 122 MB.  That tends to randomly fail after the program has been running for a while.  Improve the outcome by using the List<>.Capacity property and by removing the jitter forcing.

Comment: When the exceptions occurs, what is the memory occupancy indicated by Windows Task Manager?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Large structures are done on the Large Object Heap (LOH) and that is subject to fragmentation.

So while you probably have enough free memory you may not have 1 large enough block of memory left.

Your numbers (1M x 64) are not enough by them self, only with enough other allocations going on it would explain the issue. You could try to solve this particular issue but it's probably just the point where a larger problem becomes visible.

In general, TaskManager is not the right tool to diagnose memory problems. You need a memory profiler to find out what's going on.

It also depends on the version of your platform and on whether it is 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: What would the large structure here be? Isn't `Matrix4` too small to be on the LOH?

Comment: @Asad - Yes, but they're Value types so the List<> will hold an array of Nx64 bytes. With a large N.

Comment: Ah, so even single large objects can be allocated in chunks across the LOH (and hence result in fragmentation issues)?

Comment: A single large object will be a single chunk, that is the core problem.

Comment: @Asad No, the issue is that the backing array for the `List` is being constantly re-created and the items copied over to increase its size as new items are added.  The creation of these many large arrays is fragmenting the memory.

Comment: Windows' [PerfMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx) can be quite helpful, you can view .NET CLR Memory counters for `Large Object Heap size`, `# Total reserved Bytes`, and Process counter for `Virtual Bytes` (the latter two are interesting for 32-bit arch though).

Comment: @Servy The `List` only holds a reference to one array at a time, right?

Comment: @Asad That is correct, but the LOH is compacted far less often than the main heap, so all of the now-dead arrays can still fragment it.  Also note that for a period of time when a new backing array is needed two arrays are actually needed at the same time, until it can copy the items from the old array to the new one.